# How to pass an Object and the ActionEvent by h:commandbutton actionListener?

Tags: jsf-2.2

I can pass the ActionEvent from the JSF-page down to a method `void clicked(ActionEvent event)` by `<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{something.clicked}" ...>`

I can also pass an Object down to a method `void clicked(Object obj)` by `<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{something.clicked(Object obj)}" ...>`

But how do I pass both in a single call to a method like `void clicked(ActionEvent event, Object obj)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener />
```

You put it inside your commandButton or commandLink:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{something.clicked}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{something.obj}" value="#{obj}"> 
</h:commandButton>
```

And it fills the something.obj property with obj before calling the listener.

For JSF 1.x you can use MyFaces Tomahawk's

```
<t:updateActionListener />
```

which does the same.